Профиль по умолчанию при открытии браузера Edge
Вопрос вот в чем, Win 11, есть несколько профилей Edge, при открытии браузера всегда устанавливается один из профилей, не тот что мне нужен, приходится все время переключаться на другой который нужен. Учетная запись в системе выставлена верная. Все излазил не нашел как это настроить, есть вариант удалить профиль с которым браузер открывается по умолчанию, но может быть есть менее радикальное решение? Copilot ничего толкового не подсказывает. Благодарю за подсказки.

Все, разобрался. В панели задач был закреплен ярлык с запуском от конкретного профиля.
Удалил ярлык и закрепил на панели задач ярлык из списка программ. Все стало как надо.
